# XSL Testing child elements

Tags: xml, xslt

Here is my XML

```
<SESSION MAPPINGNAME ="example_mapping_name" DESCRIPTION ="here is some data">
  <SESSTRANSFORMATIONINST TRANSFORMATIONNAME ="name1" TRANSFORMATIONTYPE ="Target Definition">
  </SESSTRANSFORMATIONINST>
  <SESSTRANSFORMATIONINST TRANSFORMATIONNAME ="name2" TRANSFORMATIONTYPE ="Source Definition">
  </SESSTRANSFORMATIONINST>
  <SESSTRANSFORMATIONINST TRANSFORMATIONNAME ="name3" TRANSFORMATIONTYPE ="Lookup Procedure">
  </SESSTRANSFORMATIONINST>
```

Here is my XSL

```
<xsl:template match="SESSION">      
    <xsl:value-of select="SESSTRANSFORMATIONINST[count(@TRANSFORMATIONTYPE !='Lookup Procedure')]" />
        <tr>
            <td class="mapping"><xsl:value-of select="@MAPPINGNAME" /> (<xsl:value-of select="@DESCRIPTION" />)</td>
            <td class="source-definition"><xsl:apply-templates select="SESSTRANSFORMATIONINST[@TRANSFORMATIONTYPE = 'Source Definition']"/></td>
            <td class="source-tables"><xsl:apply-templates select="SESSTRANSFORMATIONINST[@TRANSFORMATIONTYPE = 'Source Qualifier']/ATTRIBUTE[@NAME = 'Sql Query']" />  </td>
            <td><xsl:apply-templates select="SESSIONEXTENSION[@TRANSFORMATIONTYPE = 'Target Definition']" /></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="ATTRIBUTE[@NAME = 'Parameter Filename']/@VALUE" /></td>           
        </tr>       
</xsl:template>
```

I have left some detail out the XML but hopefully you can get an idea of what it looks like. I am trying to pull the mapping name from session (and other attributes from SESSTRANSFORMATIONINST) but only in cases where SESSION does not contain a SESSTRANSFORMATIONINST TRANSFORMATIONTYPE of Lookup Procedure.

I thought maybe using a count of approach may be a good one. This would count the number of times Lookup Procedure appears in TRANSFORMATIONTYPE and if this is more than 0 do not pull data.

I am quite new to XSL so not sure how this would be coded. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To ensure the most helpful answer when asking an XSLT question, it's usually best if you can provide the following: (1) A sample of your input XML (reduced to the relevant parts if it's large) (2) A complete XSLT of what you have so far (reduced to the relevant parts if it's large, but still complete) (3) The desired output when (2) is applied to (1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are planning to use `count()` to decide whether to show the attribute values from `<SESSION>` or not, then the condition needs to be modified as below.

```
<xsl:if test="count(SESSTRANSFORMATIONINST[@TRANSFORMATIONTYPE = 'Lookup Procedure']) = 0">
```

This will check if the count of `@TRANSFORMATIONTYPE = Lookup Procedure` is `0` for the `<SESSIONTRANSFORMATIONINST>` nodes. If the count is `0`, then the code within the `<xsl:if>` will be processed.

The template can be modified as below.

```
<xsl:template match="SESSION">      
    <xsl:if test="count(SESSTRANSFORMATIONINST[@TRANSFORMATIONTYPE = 'Lookup Procedure']) = 0">
        <tr>
            ...           
        </tr>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

One problem here is that you appear to be trying to do two things at the same time: obtaining the session name and the values within the session. These should most likely be two different operations.

Based on what you've given us, it's hard to tell you exactly what you need to do, but it would probably be along these lines:

```
<!-- in a template somewhere -->
<xsl:apply-templates select="POWERMART/REPOSITORY/FOLDER/WORKFLOW/SESSION" />

<xsl:template match="SESSION">
  <outputSession id="{ @NAME }">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="SESSTRANSFORMATIONINST[@TRANSFORMATIONTYPE != 'oranges']" />
  </outputSession>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="SESSTRANSFORMATIONINST">
  <outputInst>
    <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
  </outputInst>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: let me try and clarify a bit here. Within each XML file there are multiple SESSION tags. I need to extract an attribute called NAME from these (code which is already written and works). Inside these SESSION tags there are also multiple SESSTRANSFORMATIONINST tags. From these I need to extract various attributes (code which is already written and works). The issue I have is that I am only interested in extracting information from the session if it does not contain a SESSTRANSFORMATIONINST TRANSFORMATIONTYPE of Lookup Procedure.

Comment: @AdamCooklin Please see my comment on your question requesting more information. If my answer is not sufficient, I think it's counterproductive to try to solve this without the required components.

Comment: I have submitted a new question on this as I was not given enough characters in the comments. It is called XSL Testing and Filtering and goes into far more detail. Thanks

Comment: @AdamCooklin You don't need to create a new question. Just edit your original question.

Comment: @AdamCooklin Thank you, that's an improvement, but still not what I asked for. I need you to provide a _complete_ example including input, XSLT attempt, and desired output. This question hinges around this `TRANSFORMATIONTYPE` so your sample input and output should illustrate what effect that attribute is supposed to have on the output.